# Having difficulties adding taglib-sharp project solution to my current vb.net solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, taglib-sharp

Hey everyone, I'm currently having difficulty adding the latest taglib-sharp solution to my current solution which contains my vb.net console project on Visual Studios 2010. Essentially I want to code everything necessary in vb and use taglib-sharp to extract all tags needed from an mp3 file. Unfortunately, when I include the solution of taglib-sharp and perform the necessary conversion visual studios 2008 to 2010, I receive an error stating "Failed to backup file as C:\temp\taglib-sharp-2.0.3.7-windows\taglib-sharp-2.0.3.7-windows\Backup1\taglib-sharp.snk". I made an attempt to build the solution with no luck. How do I resolve this?

To be quite frank I'm not sure if I need to open the solution if I just want to use the libraries for my vb program. Do I need the solution in order to use for instance "TagLib.File"?

In case you're wondering, I downloaded this library from http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.0.3.7/

Comment: When converting, tell it not to do a backup. It's not like you need to preserve the code. If you have to revert, just copy over from the downloaded archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either ignore the backup, or open TagLibSharp in 2008, compile the DLL and then reference it in your 2010 project if you only need to use the libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend installing taglib-sharp with NuGet. NuGet is the best and easiest way to use opensource libraries in Visual Studio. You dont have to compile anything, and you don't need to think about projects and solutionfiles.

To install TagLib#, run the following command in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

```
PM> Install-Package taglib
```

The NuGet distribution of taglib-sharp can be found at http://nuget.org/packages/taglib. The official source code repository is at https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp.

Comment: This now seems to be broken in NuGet. Cannot install without this error, regardless of which v. of .NET I target: "Could not install package 'taglib 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."